# Where to get latest typescript type definition for baconjs?

Tags: typescript, bacon.js

I'm in the process of updating dependencies for a project and I saw there is a new baconjs major version which I would like to use. The problem is that the last type definition I have found is one year old (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/baconjs)

Are there any other official type definition available?

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/baconjs/index.d.ts All contributors seems to be unrelated to baconjs. Which probably means the existing definitions are from a 3rd party, baconjs is very likely not even using typescript. And the next type definition update is when you make it yourself. Sorry but it's disappointingly common. Any real typescript-project is sure to update @types as part of their update/deploy process.

Comment: Baconjs is an ES6 project and the typings are 3rd party. I’ve started working on a ts version though. So there’s hope that one day it’ll be a native typescript lib.

Comment: Typescript conversion progress here: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/pull/717 Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

DefinitelyTyped is the repo for common typings and the typings are included here... https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but this is the repository used by the npm package I mention

Answer (score 0):

Bacon.js 3 has been rewritten in TypeScript, so now TypeScript is supported out of the box. See the [docs](https://baconjs.github.io/api3/index.html).